# Google URL shortener statistics in Google Analytics for external resources

Tags: google-analytics, external, google-url-shortener

I have to track clicks on shortened URLs (to external resources that are not my) in a social network posts. Is it possible to integrate Google URL shortener statistics into Google Analitics to get all in one place reports?

Comment: you can append ".info" to your google short url to get statistics eg `goo.gl/{code}.info`